# Is your fluid intelligence malleable in the positive side?

Tags: intelligence, iq, meditation

I was going through [this](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/227/how-does-raw-iq-change-over-the-lifespan-at-the-group-level) and it struck me that your raw IQ reaches its peak somewhere between 18 and 21. I came across the following [article](https://www.inc.com/melanie-curtin/want-to-raise-your-iq-by-23-percent-neuroscience-says-to-take-up-this-simple-hab.html) which says meditation could be very helpful to boost your fluid intelligence. In addition to the above articles, I also came across [Ramymond Lockey's post where he claims to have shown a change over the years after 18](https://www.quora.com/Why-arent-IQ-tests-used-for-college-admissions).

Is it true that meditation helps gain more IQ as your brain activities are slowed down (as per the second article) and this could improve the fluid intelligence as a byproduct, even during the ***early adulthood***? I'm assuming that productivity (in any form) and critical thinking abilities could be bettered/sharpened by focusing on the little details and then tap a nut *gently* at the right spot (instead of brute tapping to crack it).

Comment: I'm not a specialist, but intelligence correlates with many other healthy conducts and habits. You generally need a balanced lifestyle which includes fair share of career, study, nutrition, exercise and warm relations all at the same time. Meditation has been shown to positively influence many mental health issues. So it can at least indirectly help with one's general intelligence by improving mental health. Avoiding alchohol is also key.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of: [Is there any evidence that fluid intelligence is malleable?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/16501/7001)  I suppose this question can focus specifically on the effect of meditation on IQ.